# How to send a string in bash script to a c program and use that string

Tags: linux, bash, c

I need to send a string to a C program using a bash script, and then take that string in the C program and do things to it. The issue is I can't figure out how to use the string. I tried printf to see what the c program actually got, and it printed out random numbers.

This is the bash script:

```
length=`/home/hellboy632789/linelength $line`;
```

This is the C Program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    int length;
    char *string = argv[1];
    for(length = 0; string[length] != '\0'; length++);
    printf("%d\n", length);
    return(0);
}
```

I am fairly new to C, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the length of the string as the exit code of the C program. Bash makes that exit code available in the variable `$?`.

Your bash script, on the other hand, is putting into your "length" variable what your C program is printing to stdout, which is not at all the same thing.

Since the exit code is conventionally 0 if the program executed correctly, and non-zero if there was an error, it makes more sense to use the bash script as such and change the C code.

Replace `return(length);` with `printf("%d\n", length);return(0);` and your program should work as you wish. You can test by simply running `/home/hellboy632789/linelength testtestwhatever` at your bash command prompt.

Of course there are many other ways, but I suppose this is but a first step to something more complicated. Good luck and persevere.

EDIT: for example, this works:

```
~/316643$ cat linelength.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int length;
    char *string = argv[1];
    for(length = 0; string[length] != '\0'; length++);
    printf("%d\n", length);
    return(0);
}
~/316643$ gcc -o linelength linelength.c
~/316643$ ./linelength qwertyui
8
~/316643$ line="qwerty uiop"
~/316643$ length=`./linelength "$line"`
~/316643$ echo "length is $length bytes"
length is 8 bytes
~/316643$
```

EDIT 2: Bash will split everything that follows the command `linelength` at the spaces, except if you protect the spaces using backslashes or enclose the strings in quotes. You have two choices for arguments with spaces, either you protect the spaces like this:

```
~/316643$ line="qwerty  uiop"
~/316643$ ./linelength "$line"
length is 12 bytes
~/316643$
```

Note that this will count the spaces.

Or else you modify your C program to count all the argv[i], with i from 1 to argc-1. That will not count the spaces, so you will not know if there were several spaces between the words.

Comment: Oh, and you should check that `argc>1`, otherwise your program will fail badly if run without a parameter. `argc==1` would be a reason to `return(1)`...

Comment: for some reason it is not printing anything when I have it print length. The bash script calls the C program several times, so each time it calls it, the C program should print out the length and then return 0 to return to the bash script, but it prints nothing and then the bash script calls the program again with a new line, and then it prints nothing again.

Comment: Edit your question to put the C program that you are actually using (since the one currently there does not contain a printf at all). My crystal ball tells me that either you've missed the `\n` or the fact that (as corrected by me) your script isn't printing anything at all to the screen, just updating the `$length` variable.

Comment: There is more to my bash script, but that shouldn't affect this not printing anything. In the bash script $line is a string with spaces if that helps.

Comment: @SloanAnderson The program in the post is correct but if your argument `$line` contains spaces it will only use the first string before the first space. E.g.: `one two` will print `3` and not `7`. Is that correct?

Comment: I can figure out a work around for that, but the issue is that it prints nothing at all. I can test it separately by using a command line argument, and it will print something, but when given the $line it prints nothing. In my bash script I do print $line itself and it is indeed what I intend it to be. Just for some reason when passed to the C program it does nothing.

Comment: Something else is going wrong. Try running your script using `bash -x SCRIPTNAME` to see what it's really doing.

Comment: alright I figured it out. I still had it thinking it was supposed to return a value so something was going screwy there. Now I just gotta figure out how it can take a line with multiple spaces and still get the length. Thanks everyone

Comment: You have two choices for that. Am adding to my answer.